# NSFetchedResultsController - User Driven Changes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

## Overview

- I have an `NSFetchedResultsController`
- The user would be able to add new records (table view in **edit mode**)
- When user taps on add button, I am able to detect the event and I create a new `Car` (subclass of `NSManagedObject` that matches the `NSFetchedResultsController`'s predicate)

## Question:

- How to insert a new row in the table view when the action is user initiated ?
- Based on my current implementation, app crashes. Crash message is below.
- How to detect exactly when the model changes take effect ? (Based on the crash message I feel I am inserting the row too early)

## Note:

- I do understand model changes are detected by `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` but the problem is model is updated and I need the table view to match it.
- Normally `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` detects model changes and I can update using the delegate methods.
- My question is, since user adds row, the model is updated first, then the table view must adjust according to that.

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate

## Creation of NSFetchedResultsController:

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Car> = Car.fetchRequest()

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "color = %@", argumentArray: ["green"])

let orderIDSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Car.price, ascending: true)

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [orderIDSortDescriptor]

fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
                                                      managedObjectContext: context,
                                                      sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
                                                      cacheName: nil)
```

## Editing Style

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

    let newCarIndex = fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0

    let editingStyle : UITableViewCellEditingStyle

    switch indexPath.row {

    case newCarIndex:
        editingStyle = .insert

    default:
        break            
    }

    return editingStyle
}
```

## Commit User actions

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,
                        forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch editingStyle {

    case .insert:
        createGreenCar(at: indexPath) //Creating a new Car with color = Green
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic) //This causes the app to crash
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

## Crash Error message:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Comment: A few questions: Have you implemented the FRC delegate methods?  Have you set the delegate of the FRC? What does createGreenCar(at:) do?  Thanks.

Comment: your error says `invalid number of rows in section 1` will you post your `tableView numberOfRowsInSection` code please?

Comment: @Jake It is part of a larger project with multiple sections, the code pasted here is a simplified version for testing. This problem appears for for 1 section as well. I will update the error

Comment: @pbasdf FRC delegate is not set. `createGreenCar` creates a green car so that it can be picked up by FRC. I feel I am inserting the row into the table view before it gets reflected in FRC

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation for user driven changes and what the approach should be. At best I have only found for deleting records.

Comment: Why don't you move the data you populate the table with to a `dataSource` and not directly from the FRC?

Comment: Use the `dataSource` as a kind of buffer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166108/discussion-between-user1046037-and-jake).

Comment: If the FRC’s delegate is not set, it will not (automatically) recognise changes - you would need to redo performFetch to get it to, and then reloadData on the TV.  But the better way is to set the delegate and implement the delegate methods.  Your commitEditing style should just create the new Car, the FRC will observe this and will call the delegate methods with an insert changeType.  The delegate method should handle updating the TV - in this case, inserting a new row.

Comment: @pbasdf based on my understanding the delegate is used when the data changes in FRC and table view needs to be matched. In my case table view would be the first one to see the changes (as it is user driven), model needs to catch up. Refer the user driven changes in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontrollerdelegate

Comment: Thanks to @Jake, based on his explanation I think FRC might not be right approach. Probably best to stick with arrays for user driven changes. FRC might be designed only for model changes not for user driven changes.

Comment: That’s true for moves, but not inserts and deletes.

Comment: @pbasdf I tried doing it using delegate `didChangeObject` method to insert a new index path. It crashed with the same error. I did set the delegate

Comment: @Jake You were correct about the section ID. I have multiple sections and I was inserting into the wrong section

Comment: @pbasdf You are correct insert works ok, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Jake and @pbasdf, their suggestions helped my identify and rectify the problem.

I am answering for completeness.

## Root Cause:

I had multiple sections in my table view and I was inserting row into the wrong section. As a result the table view row count in the relevant section wasn't changing when the model had changed.

## Approach User driven updates:

## 1. Using Arrays

I feel it is better to transform the results into an array and use the array as the data source instead of the `NSFetchedResultsController` for user driven updates.

### 2. Using NSFetchedResultsController:

When user inserts / deletes / moves rows `UITableViewDataSource` methods are invoked:

- When user inserts / deletes row `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)` will be invoked
- When user moves row `tableView(_:moveRowAt:to:)` would be invoked
- Update Core data accordingly for the above methods

Updating core data will cause `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to be invoked

- In `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)` do the following:

  - For insert - add indexPaths
  - For delete - remove indexPaths
  - For move - do nothing as the UI is already up to date (User has moved the rows), later in `controllerDidChangeContent(_:)` invoke `tableView.reloadData()` after a delay of **0.5 seconds**.

#### Note:

When the user moved the row on `iOS 11.2` (using `NSFetchedResultsController`) I did encounter the following warning:

```
UITableView internal inconsistency: _visibleRows and _visibleCells must be of same length. _visibleRows
```

I didn't know how to resolve it, so sticking with the array implementation for now.